# Import-module: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: powershell, office365

I am trying to connect to Exchange Online using PowerShell ([As per this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps)) to add distribution group members.

However I am getting the following error:

```
Import-Module : Could not find a part of the path
'C:\Users\[my user account]\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_hhw3s30w.xwu\tmp_hhw3s30w.xwu.format.ps1xml'.
At line:3 char:17
+ ...             Import-Module -Name $name -Alias * -Function * -Prefix $p ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:String) [Import-Module], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

My code is as follows:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $adCreds -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber
Connect-MsolService -Credential $adCreds
```

My code has worked in the past on my machine, so I am struggling to work out why it is failing now.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you just use `Import-Module MsOnline -DisableNameChecking | Out-Null`?

Comment: Yes, PS is trying to import the module for you automatically but it can't find the module. Are you using the same PC as before? If not then you'll need to reinstall the pre-requisites or possibly the path to the module has been lost.

Comment: Try "get-module -listavailable" to ensure it's available to you. Also, isn't MsOnline now superseded by AzureAD modules?

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to try is closing and reopening PowerShell.

For me, I had deleted everything in my local temp folder earlier in the session. It seems PowerShell was using some of what was deleted.

When I reopened PowerShell, it apparently recreated the temp files/directories it needed, and `Import-Module` worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I had the same issue today. The way I fixed it was to update the module that imports modules, PowerShellGet
To check your current module version, enter: `Get-Module -Name PowerShellGet`
If you're still on version 1.x.x.x, update it with: `Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force -AllowClobber`
You may need to close and reopen PowerShell. Be sure to check the version again and compare it with what's available at https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellGet/2.2.5